# unable to select checkbox using ID/xpath.

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Using Selenium WebDriver in Java (Eclipse). I am trying to delete the mails in the spam folder in Yahoo. I am able to click the spam folder link in the left panel and see the mails but I am not able to select the check boxes. I trying select the top box which would select all the checkboxes below.

This is the code I wrote to click the spam folder and then to select the checkbox:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='spam-label']")).click();

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='btn-ml-cbox']")).click();  //selecting the checkbox
```

Please, suggest how to proceed further.

Answer (score 0):

This code is work for me it select the check box please see if it help you

```
  public class webdriver_firefox 
   {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException
         {
     WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(); 
     driver.get("http://www.gmail.com");
     System.out.println(driver.getTitle());

     driver.findElement(By.id("Email")).sendKeys("abc@gmail.com");
     try{Thread.sleep(4000);}catch(Exception e) {}
      driver.findElement(By.id("Passwd")).sendKeys("123654");
      driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
     driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div/div[2]/div/div/form/label")).click();  // this line select the check box please check this
     synchronized (driver)
     {
         driver.wait(2000);
     }
     //driver.wait(1000, 1 );
     driver.findElement(By.id("signIn")).click();
```